# Finding emails in very long text strings in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Hullo!

I've got a bit of an issue with some real dirty data (nice!) in excel, and I'd love some help.

I have cells with very long text strings. In them, there are e-mail adresses. I'm trying to extract only the e-mail adresses. I tried using the `FIND` function and `substitute` everything else out my string, but the string is far too long.

My second solution was to simply text to column the whole string, and then find the cells with an "@" in them and place them in a different sheet. For some reason, I'm absolutely stuck, and now my brain has melted, so I'm hoping some of y'all will help me!

Currently, I'm at

```
=COUNTIF(Email!D8:ZZ8,"*@*")
```

Which gives me the number of @ in a large range of columns. However, I can't seem to find the way of actually printing the e-mails in my second sheet. I was thinking of using INDEX or MATCH, but just can't seem to get to the damn thing.

In short: I'm trying to get the value of cells that contain an @ in a very large range of columns OR alternatively, extract emails in a very large text string. And my brain has melted.

Thanks!

EDIT:Example text because I've been asked what the data looks like:

There's confidential information in it, so I've changed it for something like this, which hides all confidential information, but gives you an idea of the format:

> Content that has 1800 characters automatically generated from a web
>   form, sent to an excel document, though poorly optimized because
>   governments are pretty terrible at computer stuff. Content that has
>   1800 characters automatically generated from a web form, sent to an
>   excel document, though poorly optimized because governments are pretty
>   terrible at computer stuff. email was sent by A HUMAN via AN EMAIL SERVER, a website that allows a
>   some things of various kind. In accordance with web protocol A NUMBER
>   we have set the FROM field of this email to our generic no-reply
>   address at EMAILFORWARDIDONTWANT@example.com, however A HUMAN provided
>   an email address (thisistheemailadressIwant@gmail.com) which we
>   included in the REPLY-TO field. Please reply to HUMAN PERSON at
>   thisistheemailadressIwant@gmail.com To learn more about AN EMAIL
>   SERVER visit a webadress.com learn more about web protocol A NUMBER
>   visit: a website.com/
>   http://anemailserver.emailautomaticallysent.com/wf/open?upn=a0CozdHDIYk-2F-2FE-27BDepiWoypG2sQgscftG6HHFFnds8gumLwFG5a91q5dYWchJq-2FS-2FxPwyA-2BRmi77imC9JC2ukUdYS8sqn0WplhHLgUkBT4OVuD4FxAUMSv1sBHGrqdEvBLARp6Ppqth1SdmKl2k4kG5IXQ73J2qGBxZ2FFgSa5wmQXQ9XyFyUsLSPvy4goLbRzaMIfl3u-2BNA1zx5FC2P6mN0komOQDVcbfPsUv2Qm57Fwc95UAD0E2f7ZsxOBXRKmwKSQjnA9ImBwK3wf3TY8vgTeV4N0jD05Oj4F8IK3JIssog6GVNNZ1-2BvLQnZmlVGa7h0WeuauDrGVDCeFcuFa-2BeXVdzpcwlWii2i

Comment: Can you provide some mock data to understand your need? Is VBA a viable solution? If it is you could replace all special characters except @ for an empty space, trim extra spaces, split on spaces, loop through your whole array and test with `If varArray(i) Like "*@*.*"` looking for your strings that resemble emails.

Comment: second this. Can you provide one of the long text strings you refer to?

Comment: I've edited my original post to add the information

Comment: Regular Expressions and VBA are one solution. Check this answer to see if it helps.
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39712233/revisions The only thing that would need to change would be the regex.

Comment: How are you contemplating the script handle multiple emails in the same cell as per your example? Is there actual contextual information in the string that you need to parse to determine the correct email to extract? This would increase the complexity of your script geometrically.

Comment: @nbayly My thought was to get all e-mails, and then manually remove the email forward addresses I don't want, since I know what that address is (actually those addresses are, since there are two or three).

Comment: Well your last hurdle will probably determine if you can do it sans vba or not. If you use a single formula to extract all emails you would have to concatenate the array and only `TEXTJOIN()` in Office 2016+ have that functionality. If you don't have this version I think you need a VBA solution unless someone has other suggestions. If using extra columns is possible you could have a cell for every email you extract, though you would have to assume a max number of emails per string.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the code below in a VBA module of your workbook.

(If you don't know anything about VBA modules and macros, see http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/run-code-from-a-module.html)

Run the `Extract` macro, select the cell containing the emails, click OK and the emails will be placed in the active cell and below.

The `GetEmails` function could be called directly from a range too (array formula).

```
Function GetEmails(Text As String)

    Set Regex = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    Regex.Pattern = "\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"
    Regex.Global = True

    Set Matches = Regex.Execute(Text)

    Dim I As Integer, Count As Integer, Arr()

    Count = Matches.Count

    If Count Then
        ReDim Arr(1 To Count, 1 To 1)
        For I = 1 To Count
            Arr(I, 1) = Matches(I - 1)
        Next
        GetEmails = Arr
    Else: GetEmails = xlErrNA
    End If

End Function

Sub Extract()

    Dim Cell As Range
    On Error GoTo Err
    Set Cell = Application.InputBox("Select the cell containing emails.", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Dim Arr, P As Range
    Arr = GetEmails(Cell(1).Value)
    If TypeName(Arr) <> "Variant()" Then Exit Sub
    Set P = ActiveCell.Resize(UBound(Arr, 1))
    P = Arr
    P.Select

Err:
End Sub
```